# Python, py2exe, & pyopengl ImportError: No module named win32

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, py2exe, pyopengl

When I try to build an exe using py2exe, it builds but when i try to run the exe it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
File "OpenGL\GL\__init__.pyc", line 3, in <module>
File "OpenGL\GL\VERSION\GL_1_1.pyc", line 10, in <module>
File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.pyc", line 35, in <module>
File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.pyc", line 26, in _load
File "OpenGL\plugins.pyc", line 14, in load
File "OpenGL\plugins.pyc", line 28, in importByName
ImportError: No module named win32
```

It only does this when I use pyopengl, It builds and runs perfectly with pygame and almost any other library/module I have used.

My setup.py script looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup  
import py2exe  
setup(console=['main.py'])
```

I am on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: It sounds like a missing path error -- which is strange since windows usually has the path to it's dlls already in the environment. My guess is that the library is looking for the 32 bit versions instead of 64 and the 32bit win32 location isn't in the default path. You might need to add it to setup as an argument / determine where that library should reside on the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, After another hour or so of searching I found the solution!

For anyone else who has this problem: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PyOpenGL

Comment: Make sure to accept this answer by clicking on the check mark under the number to the left! This helps us know that this has been answered :)

Comment: I will! But Its saying that I need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer :)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. Once you have more rep you can do it right away. And welcome to StackOverflow!